# How to change images on hover on and on with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I've got such a problem:
inside my `<div></div>` there are always 5 images, only 1 is visible other 4 are hidden.

```
<style>
   #id2, #id3, #id4, #id5 { display: none; }
</style>

<div>
   <img id="id1" src='image.jpg'>
   <img id="id2" src='image.jpg'>
   <img id="id3" src='image.jpg'>
   <img id="id4" src='image.jpg'>
   <img id="id5" src='image.jpg'>
</div>
```

My aim is to change them in the constant time stamp (for example 1 second) on hover.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   $('#1').hover(function(){
      // #id1 hide
      // #id2 show
      // #id2 hide
      // #id3 show
      // #id3 hide
      // #id4 show
      // #id4 hide
      // #id5 show
      // #id5 hide
      // #id1 show
      //  and so on...
   });
});
```

It's going to be used as a video preview, divs and inner images are going to be generated from MySQL DB.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yes, there are going to be multiple divs.

Comment: When mouse is over the div images should replace, after mouse leaves they should stop.

Comment: first of all change the ids to alphanumeric, something like `id1`, `id2`.

Comment: @PranavCBalan I think what he means is the regular video-preview where you move your cursor on top of the video thumbnail and it rotates through 1-5 images (taken from the video, basically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example, based on what I understood from your question:

```js
$('.preview').hover(function() {
  var $that = $(this),
      toggleFunction = function() {
     var $visibleImg = $('img:visible', $that),
          $nextImg = $visibleImg.next('img');
        
      if(!$nextImg.length) {
        $nextImg = $('img:first-child', $visibleImg.parent());
      }
   
      $nextImg.show().siblings().hide();
    };
 $that.data('interval', window.setInterval(toggleFunction, 1000));
    toggleFunction();
}, function() {
 window.clearInterval($(this).data('interval'));
});
```

```css
.preview img {
  display: none;
}

.preview img:first-child {
  display: block;
}

.preview {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview">
<img src="https://s24.postimg.org/r74b0vcu9/frame_0.gif" />
<img src="https://s24.postimg.org/a7vclm1mp/frame_15.gif" />
<img src="https://s24.postimg.org/600kcv075/frame_30.gif" />
<img src="https://s24.postimg.org/7t82exarl/frame_45.gif" />
<img src="https://s24.postimg.org/5d6912sox/frame_60.gif" />
</div>
```

Comment: Edited the code to immediately trigger the first change on hover, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Might the downvoter care to elaborate on his reasons? This does exactly what OP asked for in his comment to the question: "When mouse is over the div images should replace, after mouse leaves they should stop."